# How to phrase sql query when selecting second table based on information on first table

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have two tables I would like to call, but I am not sure if it is possible to combine them into one query or I have to some how call 2 different queries.

Basically I have 2 tables: 
1) item_table: name/id etc. + category ID
2) category_table: categoryID, categoryName, categoryParentID.

The parent categories are also inside the same table with their own name.

I would like to call on my details from item_table, as well as getting the name of the category, as well as the NAME of the parent category.

I know how to get the item_table data, plus the categoryName through an INNER JOIN. But can I use the same query to get the categoryParent's name?

If not, what would be the mist efficient way to do it? The rest of the code is in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT item_table.item_name, c1.name AS CatName, c2.name AS ParentCatName
FROM item_table join category_table c1 on item_table.categoryID=c1.categoryID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN category_table c2 ON c2.categoryID = c1.categoryParentID
```

SQL Fiddle: [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/40fdb/3)